# How to print new line in 32 bit protected mode

Tags: assembly, nasm, 32-bit, osdev

How would I print a new line in 32 bit protected text mode (using assembly)?

I tried setting the address 0xb8000 to 0, but it just started printing at the beginning of the current line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to directly manipulate the video buffer (as I understand your question), you just need to start writing your subsequent text at the address that corresponds to the first column of the second line.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my problem, here is my code: `mov ebx, 0xb8000+160`